# NSLocale preferredLanguages with only 2 charcters as returned values

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocale

The following code gives an array with all Languages,
still I would rather filter out variations like "en-GB",""zh-Hant" and have an array with only 2 characters per language.

What is the elegant Apple(ish) way to do so?

```
 NSLog(@"[NSLocale preferredLanguages] = %@",[NSLocale preferredLanguages]);
 [self.selectedArray  addObjectsFromArray:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];
```

Comment: Weren't there some methods in NSLocale that were used in order to 'convert' between identifiers? Might want to take a look at those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using predicates to filter arrays is probably as "Appleish" as it gets:

```
NSPredicate *lenIs2=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length==2"];
NSArray *filtered = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:lenIs2];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```